# Chart.js dynamic updates with data from database

Tags: ajax, charts, chart.js

New to SOF and Chart.js. Working with this line chart code: [Link][1]
linegraph.js pulls that data and adds the data to the chart.

I have tried setting up a setInterval function to dynamically update the "event" values on my graph. The graph is rendered and the initial event values added. But I am getting an error when setInterval runs to update the event data: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '9' of undefined" (line 43 - 10 items in my array)

Im not sure if I am declaring the function correctly to grab all of the values from my array, then update the graph. Please help!

Updated Code v2:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var source = [];
        var event = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            source.push("Source" + data[i].source);
            event.push(data[i].events);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: source,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'events',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: event
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata
        });


        var updateChart = function() {
          $.getJSON("data.php", function(data) {
        barGraph.destroy();                           <--------- Issue 
             for(var i in data) {
            source.push("Source" + data[i].source);
            event.push(data[i].events);
            }
        barGraph.update();

           }); 
        }         

        setInterval(function(){updateChart();},3000);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

});

New Code Update 4.17

```
     <div id="chart-container" style="width:40%">
                                <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
                            </div>

            <script> 
            var randomScalingFactor = function() {
                                    return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                                };


            // create initial chart
                var ctx_live = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
                  type: 'doughnut',
                  data: {
                    labels: ['BPM','REMAIN'],
                    datasets: [{
                      data: [80,20],
                      borderWidth: 1,
                      backgroundColor:['#FF6384','#ffffff'],
                      label: 'BPMs',
                    }]
                  },
                  options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    title: {
                      display: true,
                      text: "Chart.js - Dynamically Update Chart Via Ajax Requests",
                    },
                    legend: {
                      display: false
                    },

                  }
                });

                // logic to get new data
                var getData = function() {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/data.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                      // process your data to pull out what you plan to use to update the chart
                      console.log(data);
                            var bpms = [];
                            var remain = [];
                            for(var i in data) {
                                bpms.push(data[i].bpm);
                                remain.push(data[i].left);
                            }
                      // e.g. new label and a new data point

                      // add new label and data point to chart's underlying data structures

                    // myChart.data.labels.push("BPM");
                    // myChart.data.labels.push("REMAIN"); 
                    // myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push([bpms]);
                    //myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push([remain]);


                                   myChart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
                                            dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
                                                return randomScalingFactor();       <-------------------------------------- Issue Here

                                            });


                                        });

                      myChart.update();

                    }
                  });
                };


                // get new data every 3 seconds
                setInterval(getData, 3000);

            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO and chart.js!

Based on your code, It looks like you are not quite updating your chart data correctly.  Also, you will need to use the `.update()` function instead of `.render()`.  Here is an updated version of your code that should work.

Note, I'm not sure what format `result` is in, but you might have to iterate over it and build a new data array first (just like you did when you first created the chart) before using this example.

```
var updateChart = function() {
  $.getJSON("data.php", function (result) {
     //barGraph.data.labels = newLabelArray;
     barGraph.data.datasets[0].data = result;
     barGraph.update();
   }); 
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that chances are if you are updating your data, then you usually need to update your labels as well.  I have commented out a line above that demonstrates how to do it.  You will also probably have to take your `result` object and build your labels like you do on your initial chart setup.

Based on your latest code and comments,it looks like you are having trouble structuring you code to get this to work.  Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqaGRR) that you should be able to build from to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Jordan! You are the man! That is what I needed. I guess it was a late night... I think, my "result" object should be "data". Like so, at the end of data.php I    print json_encode($data)   .... The resulting format is [{"source":"0.0.0.0","events":"154424"},{"source":"0.0.0.0","events":"73843", etc...}] so my array has both event and source in it. Could you help me with how to build the array to update the labels also?

Comment: @devsplunk can you update your answer with your latest code.

Comment: Code updated above. Not sure, but do I still need to declare a new array?

Comment: Please see my update code v2 above with a different approach to update the data. The graph does update, but I cannot remove the old data before updating the graph. It just keeps appending. I tried destroy(), removeData(), clear() but none of them are working for me. Would you be able to assist?

Comment: Thank you Jordan, I thought it would work too but the chart just freezes. It stopped appending though ;). I'm not sure if I should regroup back to the array approach? You have been a great help, please let me know if you have any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you are having trouble structuring your overall code to get this to work.  Check out the last section of my updated answer.  I provide an example that does exactly what you are trying to do (except it uses a dummy REST API instead of calling a PHP page).  Hopefully you can use this to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this. I tried your suggestion but this method still keeps appending data to the chart. I need to just update the existing data. I can use a `randomScalingFactor()` to update the values but I cant figure our how to pass the actual new values from `bpms` and `remain` to update the chart. If you would be able to help me update these values with the foreach loop I have in my updated code above that would be awesome.